# Using C flag enums in C++

Tags: c++, c, enums

I have a C API that defines an enum like so:

```
typedef enum
{
  C_ENUM_VALUE_NONE    = 0,
  C_ENUM_VALUE_APPLE   = (1 << 0),
  C_ENUM_VALUE_BANANA  = (1 << 1),
  C_ENUM_VALUE_COCONUT = (1 << 2),
  // etc.
  C_ENUM_VALUE_ANY     = ~0
} CEnumType;
```

There is a method that uses the enum, defined as:

```
void do_something(CEnumType types);
```

In C, you can call something like:

```
do_something(C_ENUM_VALUE_APPLE | C_ENUM_VALUE_BANANA);
```

However, if you try to call it this way in C++ (Linux, g++ compiler), you get an error, *invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘CEnumType’*.

**What is the correct way to use this C API from my C++ application?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to cast `int`s to enums in C++, but you can hide the cast in a custom `OR` operator:

```
CEnumType operator|(CEnumType lhs, CEnumType rhs) {
    return (CEnumType) ((int)lhs| (int)rhs);
}
```

With this operator in place, you can write your original

```
do_something(C_ENUM_VALUE_APPLE | C_ENUM_VALUE_BANANA);
```

and it will compile and run without a problem.

Comment: It it even well defined behavior to have an object of enum type whose value is not one of the specified enum values?

Comment: I am pretty sure this entire (int) conversion is redundant because your enum has some storage type already or can be specified with enum X : int {}

Answer (score 6):

C++ has stricter rules than C regarding enums.  You'll need to cast the value to the enumeration type when calling:

```
do_something((CEnumType)(C_ENUM_VALUE_APPLE | C_ENUM_VALUE_BANANA));
```

Alternatively, you can writer a wrapper function that takes an `int` to do the cast for you, if you want to avoid writing the cast every time you call it:

```
void do_something_wrapper(int types)
{
    do_something((CEnumType)types);
}
...
do_something_wrapper(C_ENUM_VALUE_APPLE | C_ENUM_VALUE_BANANA);
```

Though I don't know if I want to see what you get when you cross an apple with a banana...

Answer (score 5):

In the case of bitwise operations, the expression evaluates to a primitive type, i.e. `int`, `long`, etc. However, your function takes a non-primitive type (`CEnumType`). The only way I know of to bypass this is to cast the expression. For example:

```
do_something((CEnumType) (C_ENUM_VALUE_APPLE | C_ENUM_VALUE_BANANA));
```

Comment: +1 for noting the expression evaluation to `int`. do_something(C_ENUM_VALUE_APPLE) would just work fine without any casts. Its because the expression evaluated to an `int` that a cast is required

Answer (score 1):

CEnumType A;

A = (CEnumType)(A | C_ENUM_VALUE_APPLE);

You can use it this way too.

Answer (score 0):

By or-ing two enum values, you're creating an invalid value (0x3 is not in enum CEnumType).  Enumerations are not bitfields.  If you want a bitfield, define one.

You can cast the value if you want to force it through, but that may surprise some code that is counting on only being able to get the enumerated values.

```
do_something((CEnumType)(C_ENUM_VALUE_APPLE | C_ENUM_VALUE_BANANA));
```

Comment: He didn't define this interface, he's using an interface defined by someone else designed for C. He presumably can't (and shouldn't) change the library code.

Comment: Enum is there for simplicity of declaration, and function is accepting enum just to hint C developer where to look for values that can be xored to form an input... Nothing wrong with that, just a different way of thinking. More like C and not C++.

Comment: "*By or-ing two enum values, you're creating an invalid value (0x3 is not in enum CEnumType)*" I think this is wrong. Its just because the bit-wise operator evaluates to int and hence the error. Not because it evaluated to 0x3 which is not in enum