# strongly typed enum classes in visual studio 11 (beta)

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, standards, visual-studio-2012

I'm playing around with the Visual Studio 11 Beta at the moment. I'm using a strongly typed enum to describe some flags

```
enum class A : uint32_t
{
    VAL1 = 1 << 0,
    VAL2 = 1 << 1,
};
uint32_t v = A::VAL1 | A::VAL2;    // Fails
```

When I attempt to combine them as above I get the following error

```
error C2676: binary '|' : 'A' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Is this a bug with the compiler or is what I'm attempting invalid according to the c++11 standard?

My assumption had been that the previous enum declaration would be equivalent to writing

```
struct A
{
    enum : uint32_t
    {
        VAL1 = 1 << 0,
        VAL2 = 1 << 1,
    };
};
uint32_t v = A::VAL1 | A::VAL2;    // Succeeds, v = 3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C flag enums in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339076/using-c-flag-enums-in-c)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I don't think it's an exact duplicate, because this question is about converting from `enum`s to `int`, which is fine with regular enums.

Comment: If the enum were implicitly convertible to a different type, it wouldn't exactly be strongly-typed... Are you sure you don't want just plain old `enum`?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/353fc67489dc/include/wheels/enums.h%2B%2B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strongly typed enums are not implicitly convertible to integer types *even if* its underlying type is `uint32_t`, you need to explicitly cast to `uint32_t` to achieve what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly typed enums do not have operator `|` in any form. Have a look there: http://code.google.com/p/mili/wiki/BitwiseEnums

With this header-only library you can write code like

```
enum class WeatherFlags {
    cloudy,
    misty,
    sunny,
    rainy
}

void ShowForecast (bitwise_enum <WeatherFlags> flag);

ShowForecast (WeatherFlags::sunny | WeatherFlags::rainy);
```

Add: anyway, if you want uint32_t value, you'll have to convert bitwise_enum  to uint32_t explicitly, since it's what enum class for: to restrict integer values from enum ones, to eliminate some value checks unless explicit static_casts to and from enum class-value are used.